# INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'InstalledSubscriberPackage' is not supported

Tags: sobject, tooling-api, package

I'm querying the tooling API via some external C# code to get a list of installed packages.

`SELECT SubscriberPackage.Name, SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix, SubscriberPackageVersionId FROM InstalledSubscriberPackage`

On some orgs, I get the error `INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'InstalledSubscriberPackage' is not supported`.

How do I make the `InstalledSubscriberPackage` object available?

I'm not sure what the differentiating factor is for whether `InstalledSubscriberPackage` exists.

I've ran the query successfully against:

- non-DevHub orgs
- DevHub orgs
- developer orgs
- sandbox orgs
- scratch orgs

I suspect that there's a setting I need to enable or permission I need to grant to make the `InstalledSubscriberPackage` object available, but I can't find what.

Comment: What details do you have about the orgs where it isn't available? Are they scratch orgs? Are they sandboxes? Are you using the Developer Console to run the Tooling API query? Are you running the query as part of a managed package?

Comment: @DanielBallinger I've updated the question to answer those, but in summary: I'm running the query in some external C# code, so not a manged package. The query has worked against scratch orgs, sandbox orgs and dev orgs, so I don't think that's the factor causing `InstalledSubscriberPackage` to exist or not exist.

Comment: I'd start by checking the permissions related to managing packages. Try "Download AppExchange Packages" and maybe "Manage Package Licenses". Can you manually access the list of installed packages via the UI? - [View Installed Package Details](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=distribution_package_detail.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks @DanielBallinger, it's the `Download AppExchange Packages` permission I need for this query to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user needs to have the `Download AppExchange Packages` permission in their profile.

[image: Download AppExchange Packages permission]

If they have the permission, the query on the tooling API returns records from `InstalledSubscriberPackage`.

```
SELECT SubscriberPackage.Name, SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix, SubscriberPackageVersionId FROM InstalledSubscriberPackage
```

If the user does not have the permission, they'll get the error

```
INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'InstalledSubscriberPackage' is not supported
```

Credit to @DanielBallinger for pointing me in the right direction here.